# Rewrite URLs for a website in a subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a website on localhost using XAMPP under Windows 7. 
The website URL is http://localhost/lyrics. How can I enable url rewriting for that subdirectory?

I tried with the code below but it didn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lyrics
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to SO!!

Make zure mod_rewrite is enabled in httpd.conf and add à slash after lyrics:

```
RewriteBase /lyrics/
```

Comment: I also tried with the ending slash but it didn't work either. 
The module is enabled and rewriting works fine for http://localhost/

Comment: What about placin another htacces in /lyrics/ Also: does the lyrics directory exists?

Answer (score 0):

Wait - so you're doing this in development and production mode, and it only works in development ( localhost ) ?

Are you relying on virtualhosts or strictly .htaccess? Can you confirm that even a simple basic .htaccess rule like ErrorDocument works in production mode?

Any reason you can't just make a VirtualHost for that directory?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName foo.localhost.com  # this needs to be in your hosts file as 127.0.0.1 foo.localhost.com
DocumentRoot C:/whatever/lyrics

* add your rewrite rules here *
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So, if I try the same rewriting rules under http://localhost (no subdirectory), it works just fine. But if I move all the code in http://localhost/lyrics/ it doesn't work anymore.

I will try with a virtual host. 
Thanks.